# How to display pop-up message after get coordinate xy of an image using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have 1 problem..I had to do drag n drop an image..then get the position of image after drop...Then, when I drag it and get the position, I need to display a pop up message using jquery..Can anyone help me? Please show me the demo and clear solution because Im new in jquery..Thank you guys!!

This is my code of dra,drop n get coordinate..now , I want to add the pop up message after get the position..In the pop up message, I want to add -->name your location and can be saved in database.

```
   $('#dragThis').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',        // sets the cursor apperance
    containment: '#dragThis2',
    drag: function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var xPos = Math.abs(offset.left);
    var yPos = Math.abs(offset.top);
    $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
    $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {

    // Show dropped position.

    var Startpos = $("#dragThis").position();
    var Stoppos = $(this).position();
   //        
    $("#dragThis").val((Stoppos.left - Startpos.left));
    var left = Math.abs(Stoppos.left);
    var top = Math.abs(Stoppos.top);
    $('#posX').text('left: ' + left);
    $('#posY').text('top: ' + top);
    }

    });
```

How to add the pop up message in my code?Please...anyone?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I've edit the latest post...Please help me!! @JamesMontagne

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alert, like this:

```
alert('xPos: ' + xPos + ', yPos: ' + yPos);
```

You would want to put it in your stop callback function. Read the values back from the DOM elements you wrote them to, or better yet, define `xPos` and `yPos` outside the `drag` function so you can access them in the `stop` callback.

If you want something more fancy, there are numerous, well-documented jQuery plugins for modal dialogs.

This is the plugin I usually go with: http://jquery.malsup.com/block/
You can also look into the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

When using block UI, you set your message like this:

```
$.blockUI({
   message: 'Set any message here as a string'
});
```

Comment: If I have this code:$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#demo1').click(function() { 
        $.blockUI({ message: $('#loginForm') }); 
 
        setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000); 
    }); 
}); 
       How do i change what to put in it??

Comment: ok,how about in my message I want to put message like this--->Set a location. Beside the message I want to put a textbox..How to do that?

Comment: ok, I've seen the demos.is there any plug in or something I have to include in my visual studio 2008 before I proceed using $.blockUI? or I can just simple take the code?

Comment: You need to include the `jquery.blockUI.js` file in `script` tags.

Comment: If I used this code---> alert('Name a location: '); how do I want to put a text box beside it?

Comment: how do I want to edit the promp? For example I want to change the ok button to save button and want to shorten the length of the text box as in the link above??

Comment: If you want control over the prompt, I recommend using `blockUI` instead of the built-in `prompt`

Comment: If use this code--->$.blockUI({
   message: 'Set any message here as a string'
});   how can I edit or add text box in it??

Comment: Please see the first demo as I posted before. It shows how to accept an input

Comment: do u know to make my code on my post works with this code...I took from the demo link that u gave---> $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#demo1').click(function() { 
        $.blockUI({ message: $('#loginForm') }); 
 
        setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000); 
    }); 
    });